# Creating TabBar Three20

Tags: iphone, three20

Is there any guide how to create this tab bars?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a tutorial on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/samples/TTCatalog/Classes/TabBarTestController.m) (c.f. TTCatalog example app)

Comment: any idea how to do it in monotouch?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience using monotouch. But that wasn't your initial question, was it?!